# where introduce adding Client1 subscription on behalf of client2 in solace guide

Tags: addition, subscriptions, solace

I want to get the introduction about a Client adding subscription on behalf of client 2,do you know where introduced in the solace guide,thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for subscription managers.

> A subscription manager is a custom coded program running in the back
>   end of your enterprise which manages subscriptions for other clients.
>   Solace enables a centralized subscription management architecture by
>   providing a special feature which allows certain clients to subscribe
>   and unsubscribe to topics on behalf of other clients.

There's a couple of blog posts on the Solace website that describe this in detail.

[An Architectural Look at Managed Subscriptions in Solace](http://dev.solacesystems.com/blog/obo-managed-subscriptions-solace/)
[Solace Managed Subscriptions in Action](http://dev.solacesystems.com/blog/managed-subscriptions-in-action/)